# Web scraping and proxy type

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, bots, proxies

Framework: Scrapy.

I am currently using a web-scraper but I am getting disconnected from the server.
The scraper will (eventually) scrape between 100k and 150k pages with each page containing 11 fields that contain data that will be scraped.

My idea is that the scraper will be used once per month.

Estimated size of database upon completion is between 200mb and 300mb (not accounting for bandwidth).

I do not know if I need a paid proxy for this or if I can use free proxies.

Any advice (or proxy provider for my needs) will be greatly received.

Answer (score 0):

there are several techniques to avoid being disconnected to the server you are scraping

this are some of the common techniques

you can add `user agents` here is a [library](https://pypi.org/project/scrapy-user-agents/) and in [this page](https://www.scrapehero.com/how-to-fake-and-rotate-user-agents-using-python-3/) there are tutorials on how to use `user agents`

you can go to your `settings.py` and uncomment `DOWNLOAD_DELAY = x`

Answer (score 0):

Without a proxy you're very likely to have your IP address blocked and then even with proxies you may run into a CAPTCHA that prevents you from scraping pages.

For scraping 100K - 150K pages per month, as you indicated, I would highly recommend not using free proxies. The problem with free proxies is that they're incredibly unreliable - you never know who's using them, what they're being used for, when they'll no longer work, etc... Which could lead to any/all of your proxies being shut down or blocked and therefore your scraper will no longer work at any given moment.

Paid proxies are certainly the way to go although they can get quite expensive and some of the proxy providers have been known to use shady techniques to obtain IP addresses.

However https://htmlapi.io (my service) can bridge this gap for you and it's free to get started with (you don't even need to create an account). HtmlAPI returns the raw HTML contents of the page you're scraping. It handles rotating proxy servers for you automatically, defeating CAPTCHA's, rendering JavaScript, and more...

All you have to do is call the API and extract the data you need from the webpage.
Try it from your command line:

```
curl "https://htmlapi.io/example.com"
```